# Restoring auto renewal subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

When restoring the subscriptions, do we have check the Subscription Expire Date for auto renewal subscription.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it doesn't matter what the expiry date is for the subscription if you are just restoring auto renewal. This is because no charges would be made until the expiry date, and I'm guessing you have a method for checking and updating that status.